# Deferred Promise - Run Functions One by One after each completes

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, deferred

I have 3 functions that make aync calls to backend systems : fnOne, fnTwo, fnThree. I know I am not doing it correctly, but cannot figure out the right way.

I am starting off by trying to call them one by after each completes:

However, fnOne already has a deferred object inside of it and when that is resolved it is resolving my promise.

```
$.when(oController._fnOne()).done(function(){
    console.log("fn one complete");
});
```

functions

```
_fnOne: function(){

    var oController = this;

 //when the deferred is done in _checkInstanceStatus, it is resolving the above, rather than the pDeferred in this function resolving the above.
$.when(oController._checkInstanceStatus(oParams)).done(function(oStatusData) {
        //does some stuff 
        return $.Deferred(function() {
            var pDeferred = this;
            //does a call for data and upon success i will resolve ..
            pDeferred.resolve();
        });
    });
}
```

other function

```
_checkInstanceStatus: function(oParams){
            return $.Deferred(function() {
                var pDeffered = this;
                //does a call for data and upon success i will resolve...
                pDeffered.resolve(data);

                });
            });
        },
```

Then the plan is to try and chain them, so they run one by one, like so:

```
$.when(oController._fnOne())
.then(oController._fnTwo())
.then(oController._fnThree())
.done(function(){
    console.log("all complete!");
});
```

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't quite enough information in the question to give you a solid answer. What is "does a call" that `fnOne` does, for instance? Is it something that returns a Promise or Deferred?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for your reply, does a call is where it is calling the backend system for data, i am resolving the deferred after that call has successfully completed pDeferred.resolve();

Comment: That call to the backend system is via what, `$.ajax`? Again: Does it return a Promise or Deferred, or...?

Comment: it doesn't return either a Promise or Deferred. It is a call to Amazon Web Services using their JavaScript API - For example, ec2.describeInstanceStatus(params, function(err, data) {... this will return the current status of a server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. There's no need to use `$.when` if you're passing it a single Deferred.
2. `fnOne` (and presumably the others) needs to **return** a promise/Deferred so you know when it completes. Since it's using `_checkInstanceStatus`, which returns a Deferred, it can do that by using `then`:

So `fnOne` might look like this:

```
fnOne: function() {
    var oController = this;
    return oController.__checkInstanceStatus(oParams).then(function(oStatusData) {
        var pDeferred = $.Deferred();
        callAmazon(function() {
            if (/*successful*/) {
                pDeferred.resolve();
            } else {
                pDeferred.reject();
            }
        });
        return pDeferred.promise(); // Or just the Deferred if you like, but
                                    // normally you want to share promises, not
                                    // Deferred objects
    });
}
```

Notice how it *returns* the result of calling `then`, which is a promise created by calling `then`. That promise will resolve based on the promise you're returning from the `then` handler.

You'd follow the same pattern with the other functions.

To chain them one after another, you'd do this:

```
oController._fnOne()
.then(oController._fnTwo)        // Notice no () on that, we're passing the
.then(oController._fnThree)      // function in, not calling it. Same on this line.
.then(function() {
    console.log("all complete!");
})
.catch(function(error) {
    // Do something about the error
});
```

*(I'm assuming `_fnOne` and `fnOne` are the same function.)*

I'm assuming a relatively recent version of jQuery that has Promises support in Deferreds.

---

Side note: I'd switch to using native Promises (with a polyfill if necessary to support old browsers) rather than using jQuery's `Deferred`, which has...well, it has a lot of history and the API has gotten cumbersome. :-)

With native promises:

```
fnOne: function() {
    var oController = this;
    return oController.__checkInstanceStatus(oParams).then(function(oStatusData) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            callAmazon(function() {
                if (/*successful*/) {
                    resolve();
                } else {
                    reject();
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Usage is the same (because I used Promise APIs that have been added to Deferred in the first example).

Comment: Appologies, a few typo's on my part too whilst trying to simplify the code! Thank you very much, this works well!! I have switched to native promises too

Comment: one last question for you - how would I pass data from one function to the next in sequence?

Comment: @neeko: You'd pass it as an argument to `resolve`, and receive it as a parameter in the target function. For instance, if `_fnOne` does `resolve("foo")`, with the chain above `_fnTwo`'s first parameter will have the value `"foo"`. :-)

Comment: ah makes sense! Also, the second function `.then(oController._fnTwo)` in _fnTwo, `this` is now the promise rather than the controller, would I have to pass the controller to fnTwo as well in order to use it?

Comment: @neeko: You could use `bind`: `.then(oController._fnTwo.bind(oController))`. Or use a wrapper function: `.then(function(value) { return oController._fnTwo(value))` (the arrow version is more concise: `.then(value => oController._fnTwo(value))` and support is good, but not universal yet).

Answer (score 2):

It's quite difficult to understand your function. So I have make it simple to define 3 new func with 3 different way so that you can understand jquery deferred easier.

```
var funcOne = function() {
  var defer = $.Deferred();
  $.ajax('/echo/json')
    .then(function(data) {
      console.log('func1', data);
      return defer.resolve(data);
    });
  return defer;
}

var funcTwo = function() {
  console.log('begin call func 2');
  return $.ajax('/echo/json')
    .then(function(data) {
      console.log('func2', data);
      return $.Deferred().resolve(data);
    });
}

var funcThree = $.ajax('/echo/json');

funcOne()
  .then(funcTwo)
  .then(funcThree)
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log('finally got func 3 data', data)
  });
```

jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/zmjLaznn/